dnf install gnutar ... bf81de15: NOKEY
I am using dnf configured for OpenMandriva Cooker, and I have this problem bf81de15: NOKEY when trying to install gnutar.
What is the procedure to do in these cases? And if it is not possible, how to omit the key?
Last metadata expiration check: 0:33:36 ago on Wed Apr  3 17:49:59 2024.
Dependencies resolved.
==================================================================================================================
 Package                  Architecture             Version                  Repository                       Size
==================================================================================================================
Installing:
 gnutar                   x86_64                   1.34-4                   cooker-x86_64                   965 k

Transaction Summary
==================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total size: 965 k
Installed size: 3.1 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
[SKIPPED] gnutar-1.34-4-omv2390.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                                   
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction test error:
  package gnutar-1.34-4.x86_64 does not verify: Header V4 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID bf81de15: NOKEY


For future reference, please always mention that you’re using “ArtEze Linux” — problems such as this one are specific to your setup, and people using typical distributions won’t run into them or be able to help you solve them. As a case in point, regular dnf-based distributions would never have a mis-matched rpm package.

@StephenKitt Alright. Now I could see that it was using BusyBox v1.31.0 rpm.

To solve this you have to do the following:
dnf install rpm

Alternatively, in case this fails, manually download the package:

http://abf-downloads.openmandriva.org/cooker/repository/x86_64/main/release/rpm-4.19.1.1-1-omv2490.x86_64.rpm

Then look for the rpm package, in the subfolders of /var/cache/dnf/, in my case the package is called rpm-4.19.1.1-1-omv2490.x86_64.rpm.
You have to manually extract the package and then copy all its files to / and replace everything.
Finally, install gnutar or any other package:
dnf install gnutar


As additional information:
You can create the rpm user and give it permissions:
adduser rpm
mkdir -pv /home/rpm

To give permissions nano /etc/sudoers and add:
rpm     ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

I currently have the repository configuration like this, sometimes it does not work correctly, but other times it does, since there are times that despite this, it deletes the packages after installing them.
[main]
name=Open Mandriva Cooker
clean_requirements_on_remove=False
best=True
skip_if_unavailable=True
baseurl=http://abf-downloads.openmandriva.org/cooker/repository/x86_64/main/release/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=0
keepcache=True

